# Is there a speed difference between global allocatable array and a dummy argument array?

Tags: fortran, global-variables, parameter-passing, fortran90

Assume that I have `a` which is a very large sized array.

**First case:** define `a` as a local variable and pass it through parameter of function `calculate()`.

```
real, dimension(:,:,:,:), allocatable :: a
...
real function calculate(a)
    real, dimension(100, 100, 100, 100), intent(in) :: a
    % some complicated calculations
    ...
end function calculate
```

**Second case:** define `a` as a global variable and use it for calculation in function `calculate()`.

```
real, dimension(:,:,:,:), allocatable, public :: a
...
real function calculate()
    % some complicated calculations
    ...
end function calculate
```

If the function `calculate()` in both first and second case do exactly same thing. Can these two programs get a difference in runtime speed? If "can" please explain to me step by step that why it happened.

Comment: There are many ways these things can be different.  But we'll need to see how the function is referenced to be able to say much.  Can you create a complete example of your intentions?

Comment: So did it happen for you or not? What are the results of your measurements?

Comment: @VladimirF Sorry for that I did not measure it yet I just ask if someone already know about this.

Comment: @francescalus I think you can just do some think like `i++` and put it to all elements in `a` for 1000 times or what ever you want.

Comment: As francescalus say, there are so many factors that asking in general this way is too broad. Especially with some unspecified mysterious *some complicated calculations*

Comment: But normally I don't care about a difference in this case, it will be small if any. A `dimension(:,:,:,:)` argument is another story...

Comment: @VladimirF How it can be possible if they do the same thing. Only different is the first case I pass variable through a function parameter and the second case I call it from global variable?

Comment: @VladimirF My point maybe "Can code in the 4th line of the first case affect to runtime speed?"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118341/discussion-between-fronthem-and-vladimir-f).